# history.js how to trigger actions outside of statechange?

Tags: jquery, ajax, history.js

I have an ajax script that uses history.js that calls a function when the state changes:

```
History.Adapter.bind(window,'statechange',function() {
    var State = History.getState();
    if (State.url.split('/').pop() === "home") {
        home();
    }
});
```

and when the history in the browser changes to home then the home() function is called, that's perfect.

Then to capture the links I have:

```
$('a').click(function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    History.pushState("", $(this).text(), $(this).attr('href'));

});
```

And when I am navigating to home from another function the home loads properly but when I click again on the home link nothing happens when I would like home to load again. I understand as there is no change in state then nothing should happen.
But then how could I trigger a load of that home() function by clicking on its link, without provoking a changestate and thus a reload?

(hint: my js level is close to 0 :)

Answer (score 0):

I did not find the way to bind to 'no change' state so what I do is when capturing the click I check if the url of the link is the same as the current url. This is ugly but right now it works.

```
if ($(this).attr('href') === History.getState().url.split('/').pop()) {
    ...
}
```